# SQL how to keep multiple entries satisfying a certain condition

Tags: sql

I have the following dataset:

```
ID  Amount
1   50
2   6
3   7
3   50
4   60
4   30
5   40
5   20
```

I only want to keep IDs with multiple entries that have at least one amount greater than, or equal to, 50. The final result would look like this:

```
ID  Amount
3   7
3   50
4   60
4   30
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use windows function `max` as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*, max(amount) over (partition by id) as max_
  from your_table t) t
where max_ >= 50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.amount >= 50
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
 select t1.* from table_name t1
where 50 >=( select max(amount) from table_name t2
                       where t1.id=t2.id)
```

Comment: Thanks! What would be my second table in this context?

Comment: @Kabobz here used one table, it is actually corelated sub-query where you can use  same table  inside subquer t1 and t2 is a use  of alias and if you you have index in id then gordon or my is answer is better than the window function solution